# MySQL fetching indexes

Tags: mysql

i am building a database, and id like to know how rows are fetched, lets say i do a:

```
 SELECT * WHERE id = 5;
```

Now, does MySQL go trough all of the columns until it hits a column with id = 5, or does it assume id = 5 is there and serve it instantly? Like apache serves files, with an absolut path being checked first?

The reason is that i am building a system which will use real time messages, this system will require alot of enteries under the same table, and to give a smooth user experience, id like to serve the messages as fast as possible.

Comment: As long as the id column is backed by a unique index access will be pretty quick (a couple of index page traversals, which on a well designed and scaled system may very well already be in memory + 1 datapage fetch), but never snapped from disk just like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It all depends on indexes.

Look at your table as a big (or not so big, actually) dictionary. If an index is properly set on the `id` column, then MySQL will search in this index and the query will be executed a LOT faster.

If no index has been defined on the `id` column, then MySQL will look for your value from the first row to the last. Like, say, if you were looking for the word "Cake" in a dictionary and ignored every common sense, beginning by the letter "A" and keeping going on, until, after 3549 words, you fall on the word "Cake".

Fortunately, indexes are easy to set (but their design can be really tricky, however), and `id` columns are always indexed in MySQL.

### How MySQL searches if there is an index

MySQL uses an optimized version of a **divide & conquer algorithm**, which is `o(n.log(n))` in complexity. Which means that if the number of items to search in grows like `n`, then the time needed to complete to request will grow like `n.log(n)`.

**How does a divide&conquer algorithm work?**

Well, let's take our dictionary back. You're looking for "Cake". So, you open the dictionary just in the middle and you notice that you're around the letter `L`. So you think, well, `C < L` so let's forget the last half, and concentrate on the first half. Then, you open the page in the middle of the first half (in other terms, the quarter). You find yourself around the letter `F`. Then you think, well, `C < F` so let's concentrate on the first quarter. And so on...

If you repeat this operation, and begin to look at the second letter of the word when you come to the `C's`, you'll find that it usually takes **less than 8 iterations** to find your particular word.

Compare this to the several thousands of words you would have had to look for if the words were totally mixed up in the dictionary.

Now, you should have a pretty good idea of the **importance of indexes** in MySQL (and databases in general).

Comment: thanks for the answer, yes i plan to have the messages field hold an array of id indexes to the messages, which will reside in another table